# SystemEvents.SessionEnding not fired until a Process (opened before) gets closed

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I'm trying to do some things in a program exacly when the user closes session.

Here is the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

public class MyProgram
{
    static Process myProcess = null;
    public MyProgram()
    {
    }

    // Entry point
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SessionEndingEvent; // Does not trigger inmediately, only fires after "myProcess" gets closed/killed 
        myProcess = CreateProcess("notepad.exe", null);
        myProcess.Exited += pr_Exited; // Invoked at "myProcess" close (works ok)
        try
        {
            myProcess.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e2) { MessageBox.Show(e2.ToString()); }

        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(); // Aplication loop
    }

    static void SessionEndingEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Session ending fired!");
    }

    static void pr_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Process Closed");
    }

    static Process CreateProcess(String path, String WorkingDirPath)
    {
        Process proceso = new Process();
        proceso.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        proceso.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirPath;
        proceso.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        return proceso;
    }
}
```

I open my application, it opens a notepad.
When I close session:

- If I have no modified anything in notepad (so it no needs
  confirmation at exit) the SO closes notepad and SessionEnding event
  is fired (so it's ok in this case) and Process.Exited later.
- If I have changed something in notepad, notepad ask me if I want to
  save, and my event is not fired until notepad process gets closed.

In other words, my program only gets the notification when the process I started is not running. I want to get my event called in any situation, regardless of whether the process is open or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the own SystemEvents thread is locked when is trying to close process, and probably is the reason that my event gets only called after my process gets killed, then there is no easy way to fix.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the session is ending? I mean by checking a variable by myself (with a timer) rather than listen a event.